# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/corba/se/idl/InvalidArgument

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I have created a fat jar for `Apache Storm` topology which contains all the dependencies. I have used `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package` command to create this jar. When I submit this jar to Storm, it gives following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.corba.se.idl.InvalidArgument
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I would like to know how to resolve this error? Which jar file contains this class?

EDIT : Adding dependencies section of `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ads.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-for-iot</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0-beta1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0_21</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

EDIT 2 : Plugins section of pom.xml

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.ats.ift.KafkaStormTopologyBuilder</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Dependencies section added into the question.

Comment: Jar gets created in my laptop and in the cluster as well.

Comment: Did you check if the file is contained in the jar (`unzip -l jarname.jar | grep InvalidArgument`) How do you build your jar? Using `maven-jar-plugin`? For this case, you need to use `maven-dependency-plugin` to extract the depended jars into local `target` folder.

Comment: No output was shown when I executed (`unzip -l storm-for-ift-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep InvalidArgument | more`) command. I have added plugin & command used to build jar in question itself.

Comment: If no output was shown, the class is not contained, ie, your jar is not packages correctly (as I assumed). Please see my answer how to package correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add something like this to your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.0_21</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It copies and extract the dependent jar into `target/classes`, which is the folder `maven-jar-plugin` expects all classes it has to package to be. This should work with `mvn clean package`.

**Update**

In your case, the will need to install `tools.jar` into maven repository first (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), because `maven-dependency-plugin` looks for the jar file there.

Comment: Did you check if the jar contains the file that is missing? Did you check, that you find the missing file in `target/classes/...`? Maybe you need to install `tools.jar` into maven repository: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Looks like problem is resolved. I installed tools.jar file from $JAVA_HOME/lib directory to ~/.m2/repository directory using mvn install command and after that this error got resolved. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

What version of Java are you deploying to? Browsing your dependencies, I find `com/sun/tools/corba/se/idl/InvalidArgument.class` in `tools.jar` of JDK1.7. But in JDK1.8 there is no such library. In fact, one of the changes of 1.8 was to remove old, non-public APIs from `com.sun` packages.

I'm afraid an upgrade of your code (to the current public APIs) is needed here.

Comment: In that case, ensure that the `tools.jar` is included in the classpath of the deployment environment.